# How to write HTML with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am horrible with JS more a Python guy :)

and I have this simple question:

"document.write" only accepts text but I want to display an iframe

```
else
{
    document.write('<p class="no">We\'ve detected that you\'re using <strong>AdBlock Plus</strong> or some other adblocking software. Please be aware that this is only contributing to the demise of the site. We need money to operate the site, and almost all of that comes from our online advertising. To read more about why you should disable ABP, please <a href="#">click here</a>.<!-- end .content --></p>');
}
```

so

```
else
{
    document.write('<iframe src="http://www.om-p.com"></iframe>');
}
```

Comment: And the problem is ... what exactly?  Your first `document.write()` also writes out a tag.

Comment: What is your question or problem?  Do you realize that you can't have unescaped linebreaks in the javascript strings in either code example like you have in your post?

Comment: @Chriswede You really need to put more effort into your questions if you want good answers. I've read all three of yours so far and they are at best cryptic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
document.body.innerHTML = "[Your code here]";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.write just like you did. All you have to do is eliminate the line break inside the single quotes. [Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/almoral/uFpHg/)